# how do I fix this blur issue on my text logo in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, text

I have a logo in PS but I'm having a  small issue.

I see this small blur at the bottom of my logo text which i cant seem to get rid of.

[image: issue logo]

Zoomed in:

[image]

can you see that small blur at the bottom of the text?

Its not very visible on some of the characters but more visible on others.

I have tried removing the stroke and the drop shadow, changing the text to crisp,smooth,sharp and all the others but the issue still remains.

Its not the font, because its happening with all fonts.

does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

That's antialiasing due to the characters having curved bottom edges. You can either move the text half a pixel vertically or manually edit them out.

Occasionally you can get better results by manually tweaking the AA on certain text. In your case, you may want to fade the grey/cyan into the white hightlight, but otherwise, you're gonna be changing the shape of the glyphs by getting rid of the partially filled pixels.

Answer (score 3):

Fixing that is called "Pixel Hinting" *(I thought it was called pixel hunting which ended up as 1 hour search)*. But it ended up with 2 good tutorials for your problem. But essentially that's AA issue happens when the form ends up between pixels (sitting on half a pixel really).

Anyway here you go:
http://methodandcraft.com/videos/pixel-hinting-vectors-in-photoshop

http://bjango.com/articles/pixelpasting/

Hope it helps you.